# could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. at real iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone

when this objective-c based method call in Simulator, it doesn't matter.
But in real iPhone device, it occurs `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

`warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.`

here is code

```
+ (NSData *)aesDecrypt:(NSURL *)url :(NSString *)key {

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
if (data == nil) {
    NSLog(@"file not found");
    return nil;
}

char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));

[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr)];

size_t bufferSize = [data length] + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
size_t decryptedBytesSize = 0;

void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128, keyPtr, [data bytes],
        [data length], buffer, bufferSize, &decryptedBytesSize);

NSData *decrypted = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bufferSize];

NSError *error;

if (kCCSuccess != result) {
    NSLog(@"aes decrypt error");
    return nil;
}

return decrypted;
}
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to fix that code several types.

- return other types.
- save NSData to files, and return nothing. read it in swift.

All of my tries can't fix the problems: No problem in Simulator, death in real device - iPhone 6 with iOS 11.3.1

EDIT) attach screenshot: **Other Linker Flags**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error message and traced it to my array declaration:

```
private var boundaries = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
```

I altered the declaration to explicitly declare boundaries as an CLLocationCoordinate2D array like so:

```
private var boundaries:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
```

That declaration silenced the error message.

In your case, you're using an old c method, malloc for your buffer instead of letting swift manage your memory so perhaps that's the problem. Or possibly  if you explicitly declared **decrypted** as an array that would take care of the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day. Just declaring the type in every variable.

Answer (score 9):

There maybe linking problem with Objective C code.

Try one of the following:

- Go to your project
- Add -ObjC to your **Other Linker Flags**
- **Enable Modules (C and ObjC)** = Yes

Comment: @Bhatt i check `Other Linker Flags` has `-ObjC`, `Enable Modules (C and ObjC)` is YES. it already done. problems still not solved

Comment: Did you try -all_load flag too, as part of Other Linker Flags? Also do consider setting Other Linker Flags like this: $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC -all_load

Comment: @Bhatt, i attached **Other Linker Flags** screenshots. i think `cocoapods` generate it

Comment: adding ` -ObjC` to other linker flags did help

Comment: confirmed, adding `-ObjC` to **Other Linker Flags** resolved this for me

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you had better set a exception breakpoint.
You can get a log about the crash.

[image]

Comment: While this is generally a good idea, an exception breakpoint does not catch this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a silly mistake but I was assigning a navigationController as the rootViewController of another UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

the error of my code was that I set the class not to the whole file, but to the main view

[correct place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0ihv.png)

[wrong place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH5Q7.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also in some cases this helps :

Open your app’s Pods-[AppName].debug.xcconfig file that cocoapods creates you’ll find OTHER_LDFLAGS and you’ll see it links to the same frameworks you link in your framework. So if you remove -framework [Duplicated framework], making the line to be OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC , the warning (it is a warning, but it actually produces crashes on runtime) disappears.