# Xcode 11.5 giving "could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data"

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos-catalina

I just updated to 11.5 and now my existing Swift program (no Objective-C, never had it) is giving this message.  To those who actually solved this problem: What is the solution? I will try reinstalling 11.5. Thanks!

Comment: Restarting and Clean build folder didn't help.

Comment: Complication: I also just took MacOS 10.15.5 before taking 11.5.

Comment: Did you trash DerivedData and restart?

Comment: Sadly no, am reinstalling Xcode now.  If it persists, I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346718/could-not-execute-support-code-to-read-objective-c-class-data-in-the-process-at and others.

Comment: That's about Objective-C code; mine's Swift.

Comment: Not really. A number of the answers talk about fixing Swift code.

Comment: Well, I can check when the install finishes, but is there a change in 11.5 to cause the message to appear? I was previously debugging, installed 10.15.5 and 11.5 and tried to continue debugging, no code change, got the message.  Looks more like an installation glitch, but maybe with a compile flag as you indicated. I 'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

Matt, I reinstalled and deleted Derived Data and it works again.  Just a glitch. Thanks for the tip!